# Positioning of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have one issue in my work  please have a look into it

Here is my Js fiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ6W3/6/)

I have a Draggable Div called **Dekey**, Initialy i set a fixed `top` and `Left.`. Initially you can see the Draggable div touching the Mountain's peek. When i click the **create** button below the image gets zoomed and the posotion of the draggable div changes. I dont want to change the draggable div from the exact position. How can i do that

**Codes**
HTML

```
<div id="conainter" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background: gray; position: relative; text-align: center;">

    <div style="width: auto; height: auto; background: blue;" id="divSpot">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;" id="image">
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="background: rgba(255, 85, 85, 0.5); z-index: 1; cursor: move; position: absolute; top:83px; left:127px; ">
            <p>Dekey</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>




<a href="javascript:;" class="ui-button" id="create-spot-btn">create</a>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).resizable({ containment: '#conainter>#divSpot'});
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: '#conainter>#divSpot'});


$('#image').load(function(){

    $("#create-spot-btn").click(function(){
        var scale = 1.2
        $('#divSpot').css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
        $('#divSpot').children('div').css('transform', 'scale(' + 1/scale + ')');

    });
});


});
```

CSS

```
#draggable { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

Comment: @ Mr. Alien Can you look into it???

Comment: Instead of showing fiddle demo place your jquery code here.

Answer (score 2):

Remove below line.

```
$('#divSpot').children('div').css('transform', 'scale(' + 1/scale + ')');
```

This is causing zoom for draggable div second time.

When you apply scaling for `id="divSpot"` it automatically scales the inner elements also so you need not to give scale again for child element.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/usiMIfEc/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i dont want to scale the child.

Comment: @Deekey oh fine. let me check

Comment: I want to retain original size of the child element and also in its exact position relative to image

Comment: Any way till now i din get any solution thanks and +1 for you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to do some math..

Since size of draggable box is 59 and size multiplier is .2 (1.2-1). So total increase in size of box after scale is 59*.2 = 11.8. We will take half of it since increase is in both side. For positioning we will translate the draggable box from half the increase in size from left.
So we will reposition the box 5.9 units towards upper left corner. Please verify it, I might be wrong. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ6W3/8/)

I have added these lines:-

```
var pos = $('#draggable').offset();

   $('#draggable').offset({top: pos.top - 5.9, left: pos.left - 5.9});
```

Thanks

Comment: Dude its a good calculation, but when i change the width of the Draggable div, it totally falling down :(